# Loading a PVR, texture problems

Tags: c++, opengl, textures, tga

I'm having a problem with loading a tga from a PVR.

I believe the PVR is loading correctly, but when I try and load the texture into OpenGL I'm getting issues.

I'm getting odd, incoherant drawings. I'll passing the entire texture file I'm making over to my graphics window class and then asking it to get the id which is an unsigned int and then create the texture.

This is my load texture class.

```
glGenTextures(animalTexture->getID(), &texture[0]);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[0]);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 3, animalTexture->getWidth(),animalTexture->getHeight(), 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, animalTexture->getImageData());
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
```

I'm wondering what the cause could be. This method does get called more than once so I'm wondering if you can overwrite a previously generated texture without any issues? Do you have to have a gluint to use to generate a texture? I'm trying to load a tga.

I know this draws successfully with a normal saved image.

Any ideas or help would be mucn appreciated.

p.s Ignore the black spot that was me.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that the format and type of your texture's pixel data is RGBA and Unsigned byte?

Comment: @arasmussen, not 100% no. Is there a  way I can find out? I persumed it was the standard.

Comment: "I'm getting odd, incoherant drawings".  Screenshot time.

Comment: @genpfault Can I screenshot? On this?

Comment: Maybe open the image up in gimp/photoshop and see if you can find out more information about the pixel format. That would explain it loading *something* but looking completely incoherant.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's RGBA. I've uploaded a screenshot. @arasmussen

Comment: PVR is a compressed texture format, so, what exactly are you passing to glTexImage2D? The compressed file? That wouldn't be right.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240293/reduce-memory-use-for-textures-in-opengl-es-1-1). Essentially, as PVR is compressed, you can't send the texture using glTexImage2D which assumes uncompressed texels (each texel being 4 unsigned bytes in the code you posted). You must use glCompressedTexImage2D instead which handles compressed formats. Have a look at this OpenGL es [extension](http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/extensions/IMG/IMG_texture_compression_pvrtc.txt) to know which internal format to use. If you're not too sure which one to choose or just want to view your compressed textures, [PVRTexTool](http://www.imgtec.com/powervr/insider/powervr-pvrtextool.asp) looks like a nice tool.